# How can i ParseExact Wed Jun 27 08:50:00 2018 -0500

Tags: powershell, datetime

Im trying to use [datetime]::ParseExact

The string i need to convert to datetime is Wed Jun 27 08:50:00 2018 -0500
I couldnt figure out the correct format to convert it correctly.

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as well:

```
$Date = 'Wed Jun 27 08:50:00 2018 -0500'
[datetime]::ParseExact($Date,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I was on the same track with `"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy KKK",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` but a bit late +1.  Just checked the number of `K`s doesn't matter [1..5] whereas it have to be `z`s [3..5].

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. To some extent it will depend on what you want to do with that time offset. Here is one way that ignores the offset:

```
$test = 'Wed Jun 27 08:50:00 2018 -0500'
$parts = $test.split(' ')
$date = get-date ('{0}{1}{2} {3}' -f $parts[2], $parts[1], $parts[4], $parts[3])
```